# How to filter based on strings

Tags: r, string, filter, dplyr

Here is a representation of my database

```
ID<-1:10
CityCode<-c("AA","BB","BB","CC","CC","CC","DD","DD","DD","DD")
strPostcode<-c("01",rep("10_11",2),rep("20_21_22",3),rep("30_31_32_33",4))
HospitalCode<-c("04","05","10","20","21","33","34","65","22","03")

mydata<-data.frame(ID,CityCode,strPostcode, HospitalCode)
```

That's a bit of background. I have the geographical origins of the patients (city codes and associated postcodes: The 2 first columns) and the geographical location of the hospitals (HospitalCode) in which they are cared for.
I would like to filter this database according to hospitals. Cities are designated by city codes and all postal codes (separated by dashes) associated with the city. A hospital, on the other hand, is only designated by the postal code. I would not be able to directly link a city to a hospital. But if the hospital code is in the city code strings (Column= strPostcode) it means the hospital belongs to the city. So I want to filter out only hospitals in the city "CC" (that is, hospital which has code 20 or 21 or 22) in order to have this table:

```
 ID CityCode strPostcode HospitalCode

1   4       CC    20_21_22           20
2   5       CC    20_21_22           21
3   9       DD 30_31_32_33           22
```

Then I want to filter on the hospitals of the 4 cities AA BB CC and DD (that is all of the hopsital code within this groupe of string of codes separted by "_": 01, 10_11, 20_21_22, 30_31_32_33). This will give me normally this table below, since hospitals with postcode: "04", "05", "34", "65", "03" don't belong to any of the four cities.

```
 ID CityCode strPostcode HospitalCode

3   3       BB       10_11           10
4   4       CC    20_21_22           20
5   5       CC    20_21_22           21
6   6       CC    20_21_22           33
9   9       DD 30_31_32_33           22
```

NB: I my real database I have hundred and thousand of Hospitals and cities. I have to automate especially for selecting all the hospitals of the all cities.

Comment: Try `subset(mydata, HospitalCode %in% c('20', '21', '22'))`

Comment: Your second case is not clear

Comment: `HospitalCode` `22` is not in `DD` though since `DD` has `30_31_32_33`; likewise `HospitalCode` `33` not in `CC`. So you're second case doesn't make sense...

Comment: strPostcode indicates the patient's residence, but the patient can be cared for in a hospital in another city. On the other hand my objective is to select all the hospitals located on one of the cities ( For example the code 22 is in CC) knowing that in my database I can have dozens of cities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you want to have a "city dataset". My example will be based on `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages.

```
city_data <- mydata %>%
  select(CityCode, strPostcode) %>%
  distinct
city_data
```

This give you the unique set of city code and their postcodes:

```
  CityCode strPostcode
1       AA          01
2       BB       10_11
3       CC    20_21_22
4       DD 30_31_32_33
```

Then you want to separate out the postcodes. The function `separate_rows` separate out the `strPostcode` and pivot your dataframe to a long form.

```
city_data2 <- hosp_data %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(strPostcode)
city_data2

   CityCode strPostcode
1        AA          01
2        BB          10
3        BB          11
4        CC          20
5        CC          21
6        CC          22
7        DD          30
8        DD          31
9        DD          32
10       DD          33
```

Now say you want all the patients with HospitalCodes associated with city `CC`. First you filter only `CC` rows in the `city_data2`, then check which `HospitalCode` are in those `strPostcode`:

```
CC_codes <- city_data2 %>%
  filter(CityCode == 'CC')

mydata %>%
  filter(HospitalCode %in% CC_codes$strPostcode)

  ID CityCode strPostcode HospitalCode
1  4       CC    20_21_22           20
2  5       CC    20_21_22           21
3  9       DD 30_31_32_33           22
```

Likewise for all the `AA`, `BB`, `CC` and `DD` (No need to filter since `city_data2` only contain those 4 cities):

```
mydata %>%
  filter(HospitalCode %in% city_data2$strPostcode)

  ID CityCode strPostcode HospitalCode
1  3       BB       10_11           10
2  4       CC    20_21_22           20
3  5       CC    20_21_22           21
4  6       CC    20_21_22           33
5  9       DD 30_31_32_33           22
```

Comment: Thank you. It is exactly what I would like to to do